# Why can I not create a node of a specific Document Type in Umbraco 4?

Tags: umbraco

How do I get an existing *Document Type* to show up in the *Create* dialogue of Umbraco 4.

I installed the BlogForUmbraco4_1.0.0 package, which I realize tries to install as the primary site, but it also installs all of the necessary *Document Types*, including *Blog*, and *BlogPost*.  Why are they not an option when creating a new item within my site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Umbraco uses a permission based Document Type Hierarchy, to ensure that editors doesn't create weird page types in wrong places (like a 'Homepage' beneath a blog or a 'News Item' inside a Gallery).

So you'll need to allow the Document Type that you wish to appear in your create dialog to the Document Type of the page you're using as the parent (this might sound like non sense ;-)).

- So, say that you've imported the Blog4Umbraco package and wants to allow a blog below a Home page, you should find out which Document Type that home page is (look at the properties tab on the document and look at the 'Document Type').
- Go to settings section and open Document types and click on that doc type (let's just say it's called 'Homepage')
- Click on the 'Structure' tab and you'll see a list of all Document Types in your install. Some of them are already checked and those are the ones that are allowed beneath that type. To allow blogs, simply check the 'Blog' document type as well :-)

Comment: Thanks, that was a 'duh' moment.